# Magento2 - Understanding dev/travis/before_script.sh

Tags: travis, continuous-integration

I am trying to set up Travis to be used as our Continuous integration server. Magento comes with a `.travis.yml` where it has:

```
matrix:
    - TEST_SUITE=unit
    - TEST_SUITE=integration INTEGRATION_INDEX=1
    - TEST_SUITE=integration INTEGRATION_INDEX=2
    - TEST_SUITE=integration INTEGRATION_INDEX=3
    - TEST_SUITE=static
```

and `dev/travis/before_script.sh`

```
        # divide test sets up by indexed testsuites
    i=0; j=1
    for test_set in $test_set_list; do
        test_xml[j]+="            <directory suffix=\"Test.php\">$test_set</directory>\n"

        if [[ $j -eq $INTEGRATION_INDEX ]]; then
            echo "  + including $test_set"
        else
            echo "  - excluding $test_set"
        fi

        i=$((i+1))
        if [ $i -eq $test_set_size ] && [ $j -lt $INTEGRATION_SETS ]; then
            j=$((j+1))
            i=0
        fi
    done
```

Am I reading it right - that the above does nothing but split the tests up into three test_suites so that we don't go over some presumable limit set by `travis-ci.org`?

Comment: I think to, too. But I'm not sure enough to provide a real answer